# Jersey: parsing json key with colon

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

For example i want to parse the following Json:

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "status": "SHUTOFF",
            "updated": "2014-08-05T06:42:19Z",
            "hostId": "038d4d27e44754af0a4d163ab981e33930bf1a66450fa260d5459b8d",
            "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "dev-desktop"
        }
    ]
}
```

The class i used to do this should be:

```
public class Server 
{
   private String status;
   private String updated;
   private String hostId;

   @XmlElement(name = "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host")
   private String OS_EXT_SRV_ATTR_host; 
}
```

here is the log of Glassfish server when i attempt to trasform json to class:

```
Grave:   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:644)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:988)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:833)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:768)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ScopedJaxrsResponse.access$001(ScopedJaxrsResponse.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ScopedJaxrsResponse$1.call(ScopedJaxrsResponse.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ScopedJaxrsResponse.readEntity(ScopedJaxrsResponse.java:74)
    at controller.project.control.ProjectEngine.getServersDetails(ProjectEngine.java:62)
    at controller.ProxyRestApi.getServersDetails(ProxyRestApi.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy344.getServersDetails(Unknown Source)
    at controller.__EJB31_Generated__ProxyRestApi__Intf____Bean__.getServersDetails(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrate
Grave:   gy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-25016] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A namespace for the prefix OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host was not found in the namespace resolver.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-25016] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A namespace for the prefix OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host was not found in the namespace resolver.
]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:557)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-25016] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A namespace for the prefix OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host was not found in the namespace resolver.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.setupSession(XMLContext.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.setupSession(XMLContext.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context$ContextState.<init>(Context.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1018)
    ... 104 more
```

Is there any escape character in order to prevent the problem of the colon in Json key? This is the first idea comes to mind but surely there are other better ways to solve this issue.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the namespace separator character:

```
jsonMarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR, '.');
jsonUnmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR, '.');
```

I used `.` but you'll have to choose the proper character.

Also, your json `servers` element is an array but your target is a simple object. Just pointing it out...

In order to set these features directly into the client:

```
final MoxyJsonConfig moxyJsonConfig = MoxyJsonConfig()
        .setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper)
        .setNamespaceSeparator(':');

final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    // The line below that registers MOXy feature can be
    // omitted if FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE is
    // not disabled.
    .register(MoxyJsonFeature.class)
    .register(jsonConfigResolver)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks! How and where can I set the instructions above?

Comment: See the edits in the answer. There's good information in the latest Jersey docs at (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a json payload being returned from Akamai https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/akamaiopen2lunapapiproduction/reference/edge-hostnames.html whereby a key contained a colon.

I finally got it work after much trial and error based on the answer above from Baldy and the javadoc https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy

Your code will need to be something like ...

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature;
```

...

```
ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();

boolean initDefaultProperties = true;
MoxyJsonConfig moxyJsonConfig = new MoxyJsonConfig(initDefaultProperties);
moxyJsonConfig.setNamespaceSeparator(':');

Map<String, String> namespacePrefixMapper = new HashMap<String, String>();
namespacePrefixMapper.put("OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR");
moxyJsonConfig.setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper);

builder.register(MoxyJsonFeature.class);
builder.register(moxyJsonConfig.resolver());

Client client = builder.build();

WebTarget target = client.target("https://www.xxxxxxx.com/restApi/v0");

WebTarget resourceWebTarget = target.path("serverStatus").queryParam("status","SHUTOFF");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = resourceWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

// GET ...
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
System.out.println(response.getHeaders());

if (response.getStatus() == 200)
{
  ServerStatusResponse statusResponse = response.readEntity(ServerStatusResponse.class);
  for (Server s : statusResponse.getServers()) {
    System.out.println(s.getOSEXTSRVATTRHost());
  }
}
```

Then assuming pojos like the following .. check the annotation being used on the OSEXTSRVATTRHost setter ...

```
public class Server {

  private String status;
  private String updated;
  private String hostId;
  private String OSEXTSRVATTRHost;

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public String getUpdated() {
    return updated;
  }

  public void setUpdated(String updated) {
    this.updated = updated;
  }

  public String getHostId() {
    return hostId;
  }

  public void setHostId(String hostId) {
    this.hostId = hostId;
  }

  public String getOSEXTSRVATTRHost() {
    return OSEXTSRVATTRHost;
  }

  @XmlElement(namespace="OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR", name="host")
  public void setOSEXTSRVATTRHost(String OSEXTSRVATTRHost) {
    this.OSEXTSRVATTRHost = OSEXTSRVATTRHost;
  }
}
```

and server status response class ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServerStatusResponse {

  private List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<Server>();

  public List<Server> getServers() {
    return servers;
  }

  public void setServers(List<Server> servers) {
    this.servers = servers;
  }

}
```